# Need to create partitioned materialized in big query

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using this big query sql query to create a materialized view.

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  `xyz.y_mv`
PARTITION BY date
OPTIONS (enable_refresh = true, refresh_interval_minutes = 1440)
AS 
(
SELECT
TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(time_stamp, DAY) as date,
COUNT(uid) ,
SUM(money),
APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT(uid) as no_of_unique_users,
FROM `xyz` WHERE tx="x"
Group by date
);
```

My base table is partioned on time_stamp

Error :Partitioning column of the materialized view must either match partitioning column or pseudo-column of the base table, or be a TIMESTAMP_TRUNC over it.

Could not find anything. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The partitioned column of your materialized view must target on the partitioned column of the base table, example

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_project.my_dataset.my_base_table (
  employee_id INT64,
  transaction_time TIMESTAMP)
  PARTITION BY DATE(transaction_time);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW my_project.my_dataset.my_mv_table
  PARTITION BY DATE(transaction_hour)
AS (
  SELECT
    employee_id,
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(transaction_time, HOUR) AS transaction_hour,
    COUNT(employee_id) AS cnt
  FROM
    my_dataset.my_base_table
  GROUP BY
    employee_id,
    transaction_hour
);
```

In this example `transaction_hour` targets on `transaction_time` from the base table which is a partitoned column.

You can the check the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-create) to have more informations or examples.